# C# Memory Mapped File - Better read or write sequentially?

Tags: c#, memory-mapping

I have two file of about **50GB** each: an *input* and an *output* file.
I am using **Memory Mapped File** to manage these two files.

The *input* file contains **3** millions of Web pages, and after I have decided a **permutation** **π** of them, I have to write into the *output* file the Web pages in the new order.

So, I can choose to read **sequentially** the *input* file and write the web pages in **different location** of the *output* file, accordingly to the **permutation** **π**. 
Or I can do the opposite: reading **randomly** the *input* file according to the **permutation** **π** and write **sequentially** into the *output* file.

Which option is faster? Why?

Comment: [Which is faster?](http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: In addition to the valid points in the "performance rant" link, it will depend on the underlying hardware.  In many cases, there is likely to be little difference.  Just try both on *your* hardware and see what is faster.

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR: Due to caching, all file-append operations are sequential.  Even writes to the middle of files will be elevator sorted and performed at block size, etc.

Random writing tends to be faster than random reading for several reasons:

1. When a file grows, the filesystem can choose where to put the new block.
2. Writes don't have to be performed immediately, the write buffer can assure that an entire block is written at once, meaning that data won't be added to an existing block, which already has a location.
3. Your processing can't take place until reads complete.  And reading relies on a predictive cache.  The OS is good at pre-caching sequential reads, horrible for random reads.  If your reads are less than block sized, things are even worse -- the actual amount of data read from the disk will be greater than the size of the file.

Comment: Are you sure that Windows will buffer writes for a non-trivial period of time?  That would mean that a power loss or crash would cause a data loss.  Hardware that offers a write cache typically will not enable the cache unless a battery backup is present to ensure pending writes complete.  It would be very odd if the operating system were less concerned with data integrity.

Comment: Some of this does not apply to SSD storage.

Comment: @Eric: The effects are less pronounced, but SSDs still benefit from sequential readahead.  It should go without saying that power loss causes data loss.  What the OS and filesystem typically try to provide are write barriers -- if the application flushes, then either everything before the barrier gets written through to the disk, or nothing after the barrier does.  However these guarantees are incompatible with RAID, so serious databases have logic for recovering even when they are violated.

Comment: Do you have a reference for sequential read ahead for SSD's?  I'm not doubting you, just curious.